# How to increase test coverage for below code?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

```
for (Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength, ParentId from Attachment 
where ParentId = :OppMapByIDs.keySet()]){

   Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
   efa.setFileName(a.Name);
   efa.setBody(a.Body);
   if(fileAttachmentWithOpp.containsKey(a.ParentId)){
       List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> listOfAttachments = fileAttachmentWithOpp.get(a.ParentId);
       listOfAttachments.add(efa);
       fileAttachmentWithOpp.put(a.ParentId, listOfAttachments);
   } else {
       fileAttachmentWithOpp.put(a.ParentId, new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>{efa});
   }   
}
```

Test Class Code:

```
@isTest
private class OpportunityMatchingHelperTest {

    private static testMethod void testCreateRecord() {

    Id conRecID = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Student').getRecordTypeId(); 
    Id oppRecID = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Internship Opportunity').getRecordTypeId();  

        Test.startTest();

        //EmailTemplate e = new EmailTemplate (developerName = 'test', FolderId = '00D9E0000000RbDUAU', TemplateType= 'Text', Name = 'test'); 
        //Insert e;
        //System.debug('EmailTemplate' + e);

        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'test');
        Insert acc;
        System.debug('Account' + acc);

        Contact con = new Contact(Lastname = 'test con',Email = 'test@gmail.com',AccountId = acc.Id,Academic_Standing__c = 'Good Standing',recordTypeId = conRecID);
        Insert con;
        System.debug('Contact' + con);

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(AccountId = acc.Id,recordTypeId = oppRecID,Name = 'Demo',StageName = 'Demo',CloseDate = System.Today(),Key_Contact__c = con.Id);
        Insert opp;
        System.debug('Opportunity' + opp);

        alu_Opportunity_Matching__c aluOpp = new alu_Opportunity_Matching__c(Opportunity__c = opp.Id,Applicant_Student_Record__c = con.Id, Application_Status__c = 'Potential Candidate');
        Insert aluOpp;
        System.debug('Opportunity Matching' + aluOpp);

        aluOpp.Application_Status__c = 'Pitched';
        Update aluOpp;

         List<Attachment> attList = new List<Attachment>();
            for(Integer i=0;i<6;i++){
             Attachment Attac =new Attachment();
             Attac.Name='Unit Test Attachment';
             Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
             Attac.body=bodyBlob;
             Attac.parentId=con.id;
             attList.add(Attac);
            }
         insert attList;

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your test class? And show us what you have written?
What problem you are facing, writing test classes?

Comment: I have added test class .

Comment: To get into your loop, your test needs to insert at least one `Attachment` record whose `parentId` is in the keyset of your `OppMapByIDs` map. I assume, based on the name of your map, that your `parentId` should point to an `Opportunity` (you're currently setting the `parentId` to a `Contact`). You haven't provided enough context to know if that is indeed the case. Your 'test' is also missing the most important part, assertions.

Answer (score 1):

In your main class I can see

```
for (Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength, ParentId from Attachment 
where ParentId = :OppMapByIDs.keySet()])
```

Which you are looking for Attachments whre ParentID is Opportunity Id.

But in you test class, you are assigning the ParentId as contact.id that is why you are failing to get coverage.

```
List<Attachment> attList = new List<Attachment>();
            for(Integer i=0;i<6;i++){
             Attachment Attac =new Attachment();
             Attac.Name='Unit Test Attachment';
             Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
             Attac.body=bodyBlob;
             Attac.parentId=opp.id;//con.id; Parent ID should be opportunityID
             attList.add(Attac);
            }
```

Making the parentId as opportunityId will solve your problem.

I would advise you to  go through the below trailhead
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro

Cheers

Comment: Attachment are under Contact and In Map I'm retrieving ContactId that's reason I used to pass ContactId as ParentId

Comment: Post complete code of Main class. We dont know what you are storing in OppMapByIDs. By name it should be opportunity